# What's an appropriate DAO structure with jpa2/eclipselink?

Tags: orm, jpa, dao, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

I've JPA entities and need to perform logic with them. Until now a huge static database class did the job. It's ugly because every public interface method had an private equivalent that used the EntityManager, to perform transactions. But I could solve that having a static em too!
However i'm wondering if that's an appropriate design, especially as the class is responsible for many things.
Not surprisingly, the code i  found online of real projects was not easy to understand (i might then as well remeain with my code). 
The code [here](http://www.google.com/url?q=http%3A%2F%2Fbalusc.blogspot.com%2F2008%2F07%2Fdao-tutorial-data-layer.html&sa=D&usg=AFQjCNHaBEmygq7pSxFAUTTAddfPHO6gZA) is easy to understand, although maybe over generic? Anyway, on top of JDBC. Yet, insightful, why use factories and singletons for DAOs?

I've though of singletoning the em instance as follows:

```
private static final Map<String, EntityManager> ems = new HashMap<String, EntityManager>();
private final EntityManager em;
private final EntityManagerFactory emf;

public void beginTransaction() {
    em.getTransaction().begin();
}

public void commitTransaction() {
    em.getTransaction().commit();
}

public Database(final String persistenceUnitName) {
    if(ems.containsKey(persistenceUnitName)){
        em = ems.get(persistenceUnitName);
    }else{
       ems.put(persistenceUnitName, em = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(persistenceUnitName).createEntityManager());
    }
    emf = em.getEntityManagerFactory();
    this.persistenceUnitName = persistenceUnitName;
}
```

This way creation of instances is standard, still maintaining a singleton Connection/EntityManager.
On the otherhand I wondered whether there was the need to singleton ems in the first place?
The advantage is with multiple ems I run into locking problems (not using em.lock()).

Any feedback? Any real-world or tutorial code that demonstrates DAO with JPA2 and eclipselink?

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I don't see the added value of shielding the `EntityManager` (which is an implementation of the [Domain Store](http://www.corej2eepatterns.com/Patterns2ndEd/DomainStore.htm) pattern) with a [DAO](http://www.corej2eepatterns.com/Patterns2ndEd/DataAccessObject.htm) and I would use it directly from the services, unless switching from JPA is a likely event. But, quoting [An interesting debate about JPA and the DAO](http://www.java.net/blog/2009/02/07/interesting-debate-about-jpa-and-dao):

> Adam said that he met only very few cases in which a project switched the database vendor, and no cases in which the persistence moved to a different thing than a RDBMs. Why should you pay more for a thing that it's unlikely to happen? Sometimes, when it happens, a simpler solution might have paid for itself and it might turn out to be simpler to rewrite a component.

I totally share the above point of view.

Anyway, the question that remains open is the lifecycle of the `EntityManager` and the answer highly depends on the nature of your application (a web application, a desktop application).

Here are some links that might help to decide what would be appropriate in your case:

- [Re: JPA DAO in Desktop Application](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=tree&th=152546&)
- [Using the Java Persistence API in Desktop Applications](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/persistenceapi/)
- [Eclipselink in J2SE RCP Applications](http://www.weheartcode.com/2008/08/27/eclipselink-in-j2se-rcp-applications/)
- [Developing Applications Using EclipseLink JPA (ELUG)](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Developing_Applications_Using_EclipseLink_JPA_%28ELUG%29)
- [An interesting debate about JPA and the DAO](http://www.java.net/blog/2009/02/07/interesting-debate-about-jpa-and-dao)

And if you really want to go the DAO way, you could:

- use [Spring JPA support](http://www.springframework.org/docs/reference/orm.html),
- use some generic DAO library like [generic-dao](http://code.google.com/p/generic-dao/), [krank](http://code.google.com/p/krank/), [DAO Fusion](http://code.google.com/p/daofusion/),
- roll your own generic DAO.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using Spring 3. Just follow [their documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-jpa) for a clean design.